# Understanding Relationship Within the F Test

Tags: self-study, anova, f-test

*When conducting a one-way ANOVA, the _______ the between-treatment variability is when compared to the within-treatment variability, the _______ the value of FDATA will be tend to be.*

*a. smaller, larger

b. smaller, smaller

c. larger, larger

d. smaller, more random

e. larger, more random*

From my understanding, the statistic being discussed is given by $$F = {{MSTR} \over {MSE}}$$
where I assume, converting to the question's terms, $MSTR$ refers to the "between-treatment variability" and $MSE$ refers to the "within treatment variability".

My question arises from the fact that options **b** and **c** seem to be good answers.
Larger $MSTR$ appear to be related to larger $F's$ in the same way smaller $MSTR$ would be related to smaller $F's$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.